# How to adjust the x labels on seasonal_decompose()?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I'm trying to rotate the x label on seasonal_decompose(), from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal. However, I only got the from the residuals to change. How can I edit all of them?

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

result = seasonal_decompose(df, model='additive', freq=3);
result.plot();
plt.xticks(rotation=90);
```